# How to manually register TortoiseGit as a `github-windows` protocol handler?

Tags: tortoisegit

TortoiseGit has an install-time checkbox to register itself as the handler of the `github-windows` protocol in browsers, however, it does not work for me on one particular computer (I've seen it working on others). I tried uninstalling a reinstalling, nothing helps.

What does the checkbox technically do? Can I edit the Windows registry or something like that to fix the issue?

Answer (score 4):

TortoiseGit actually sets these values:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\github-windows]
"URL Protocol"=""
@="URL: Github-Windows Protocol"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\github-windows\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Program Files\\TortoiseGit\\bin\\TortoiseGitProc.exe"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\github-windows\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\TortoiseGit\\bin\\TortoiseGitProc.exe\" /urlhandler:\"%1\""
```

(see https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/blob/master/src/TortoiseGitSetup/StructureFragment.wxi)

A Repair should also have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, GitHub for Windows didn't remove `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\github-windows` from registry which caused TortoiseGit not to install its own handler. After I removed it manually from registry and reinstalled TortoiseGit, all worked fine.

(BTW there is also `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\github-windows` left by GH4W but it doesn't seem to be causing any issues.)